# Snowpack says Im missing index.js when I'm not

Tags: reactjs, powershell, snowpack

Thanks for reading my question.

I successfully made a React JS App from scratch on my other PC using snowpack. And I tried it on my other one. But when I set everything up in powershell(where Im running the npm start from), it keeps telling me snowpack cant find index.js.

```
    [snowpack] [404] Not Found (/.src/index.js)
```

So now my browser is just blank at the localhost.

Here is the code:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "02",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Practice 3",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "snowpack dev",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "V",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "snowpack": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>02</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="module" src=".src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<div>Whats good React?</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[path structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7he9.png)

Apparently a jsx. compies down to a .js like it did on my other machine.

I tried to rename the index file to a normal .js. No difference. I encountered this issue before. But oddly, last time on my other machine I just closed powershell and ran 'npm start' again and it worked. Tried that thrice this time, no change. I also previously had a issue calling 'react' from both 'React' and 'ReactDOM' but fixed that setting 'react-dom' instead of 'react'.

Don't know why its saying this.

Im using webstorm IDE.

Thanks in advance.